# fork join within for loop in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog

Problem: What will be the output of this code? and why?

```
module tb;
int i;

  initial begin
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
      begin
        fork
          #1 $display("Value = %d", i);
        join_none
      end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

To spawn the fork threads with all the possible index values, you can use automatic variable inside for loop,

```
module tb;
  int i;

  initial begin
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
      begin
        automatic int j = i;
        fork
          #1 $display("Value = %d", **j**);
        join_none
      end
  end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
Value =           0
Value =           1
Value =           2
Value =           3
Value =           4
Value =           5
Value =           6
Value =           7
Value =           8
Value =           9
```

[EDA Playground link](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Pij3)

To understand the automatic variable lifetime concept including 'fork inside for', please refer to SV LRM "6.21 Scope and lifetime" or you can find many threads on this topic such as: [fork join_none inside for loop](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/fork-joinnone-inside-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The example starts 10 parallel threads of $display and schedules each #1 in the future.  They print the value 10 because there is no time to block (join_none does not block at all) the loop so the loop executes all its iterations at t=0.

Added some printing of the execution time so that its easier to see what is happening.  The thread of execution does not wait for any of them to finish (join_none) so the final print executes at t=0;

[image: code]

The simulation output is here

[image]

If you need further research see IEEE 1800-2017 section 9.3.2 parallel blocks.
https://standards.ieee.org/standard/1800-2017.html

If you want to run it go to www.edaplayground.com,and you can run it with the industry standard tools almost free (need to register with an email).